# Trying to generate a downloaded zip file containing multiple pdfs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, download

I have a requirement to call a java code from my existing application code (spring boot), which will get multiple pdfs based on URLs provided and zip them and get them downloaded in my browser window. I have written below code,

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet ( "/downloadServlet1" )
public class DownloadServlet1 extends HttpServlet
{

    protected void doGet ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println ( "reached here" );
        List < String > fileUrls = List.of ( "http://www.w3.org/wai/er/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
            "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf"
        // Add more file URLs as needed
        );

        System.out.println ( "reached here fileUrls " + fileUrls );
        response.setContentType ( "application/zip" );
        response.setHeader ( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"download.zip\"" );

        try (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream ( response.getOutputStream ( ) ))
        {
            System.out.println ( "Inside zipOutputStream" );
            for ( String fileUrl : fileUrls )
            {
                System.out.println ( "Inside fileUrl " + fileUrl );
                downloadFile ( fileUrl, zipOutputStream );
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
            // Handle exception appropriately
        }
    }

    private void downloadFile ( String fileUrl, ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream ) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println ( "Inside download" );
        try (InputStream in = new URL ( fileUrl ).openStream ( ))
        {
            String fileName = fileUrl.substring ( fileUrl.lastIndexOf ( '/' ) + 1 );
            System.out.println ( "Inside fileName " + fileName );

            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry ( new ZipEntry ( fileName ) );

            byte[ ] buffer = new byte [ 2048 ];
            int length;
            while ( ( length = in.read ( buffer ) ) > 0 )
            {
                zipOutputStream.write ( buffer, 0, length );
                System.out.println ( "writing done" );
            }

            zipOutputStream.closeEntry ( );
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any exception. getting all loggers till end and getting everything as successful, but still no file is getting downloaded in browser.

FYI, I invoking this servlet from my rest api controller as below,

```
@RestController
public class ZipController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String testing() throws IOException {
        
        String downloadServletUrl = "http://localhost:8083/downloadServlet1";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(downloadServletUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            System.out.println("value of connection "+ connection.getURL());

            // Check response code and handle accordingly
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // File download was successful
                System.out.println("Files downloaded successfully.");
            } else {
                // Handle error
                System.err.println("Error downloading files. Response Code: " + responseCode);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle exception appropriately
        }
        return "Testing zip";
    }
}
```

I a getting "Testing zip" in browser output when hitting http://localhost:8083/hello which means api is not failing anywhere, still not getting zipped file as downloaded file.

Below are the logs :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.2.2)[0;39m

[2m2024-02-09T17:52:16.413+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.e.demo.ZipFinalProject1Application    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting ZipFinalProject1Application using Java 17.0.9 with PID 32344 (C:\bag-manager\v6-project\git-project\ZipFinalProject-1\target\classes started by 10722114 in C:\bag-manager\v6-project\git-project\ZipFinalProject-1)
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:16.415+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.e.demo.ZipFinalProject1Application    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:17.135+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port 8083 (http)
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:17.146+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:17.146+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:17.201+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:17.202+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 745 ms
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:17.478+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port 8083 (http) with context path ''
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:17.487+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.e.demo.ZipFinalProject1Application    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started ZipFinalProject1Application in 1.36 seconds (process running for 2.037)
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:22.573+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8083-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:22.573+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8083-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2024-02-09T17:52:22.574+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32344[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8083-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 1 ms
value of connection http://localhost:8083/downloadServlet1
reached here
reached here fileUrls [http://www.w3.org/wai/er/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf, http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf]
Inside zipOutputStream
Inside fileUrl http://www.w3.org/wai/er/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf
Inside download
Inside fileName dummy.pdf
Inside fileUrl http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf
Inside download
Inside fileName pdf-test.pdf
writing done
Files downloaded successfully.
```

Comment: What is the content of the request body if you use your testing method?

Comment: I am not passing anything in request body. My target is to test this code inside DownloadServlet1. So I have written this ZipController so that I can invoke the logic written inside DownloadServlet1.